# How can I check or get the toolbar value of a browser with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to find out in Javascript if the toolbar property value of a Browser is either Yes or No. I know how to set it with a windows.open toolbar=no but I want to know how can I retrieve that value using Javascript. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this using javascript.